# Convert String to ReadOnlyMemory<byte> in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to convert a String to a ReadOnlyMemory object. It's easy to convert a string to a ReadOnlyMemory object (using [.AsMemory()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions.asmemory?view=net-5.0#system-memoryextensions-asmemory(system-string))) but there's no direct way to convert that to type byte, or directly convert the string otherwise.

Comment: A string is a UTF16 sequence of Char values, not bytes. Why convert to `byte`? That requires a specific encoding to be used.

Comment: There's no way to convert a string to byte[] but you answer exactly with how to convert a string to byte[]?

Comment: ...because you're working with an API that requires a ReadOnlyMemory<byte> array for some reason, and there is no direct conversion which is why I posted the answer I did?

Comment: I already commented that there *is* a way, that actually reuses memory. That's the whole point of `Memory<>`. Which depends on what you want to do. So what do you want to do?

Comment: I have a String, and I have to pass it to a 3rd-party API that requires a ReadOnlyMemory<byte>. I agree that it is a silly problem for me to be solving. I did not write the 3rd-party API.

Comment: I would be glad to hear a better or more efficient way, but perhaps you should post that as an answer instead of just implying that it exists and is obvious?

Comment: I already posted the link to the classes. The answer is little more than what I wrote in the comments. Again, how do you intend to use that `Memory<>`? It *matters*. It's better to write to a `PipeWriter` directly than create an intermediate buffer. The whole point of `Memory<>`, `Span<>` and Pipelines is memory efficiency through buffer reuse

Comment: Memory efficiency isn't a silly problem. It can lead to 10-100x better performance *at least* by avoiding both memory allocations *and* garbage collection. GC is expensive and bogs down the application when it happens. ASP.NET Core is so much faster precisely because it tries to avoid wasting memory

Comment: I really have no idea what this 3rd-party API is doing with the memory I give it or why it needs to be as a direct ReadOnlyMemory reference instead of something normal like a byte[] or a string. I highly doubt it is using it in a perfectly efficient manner once I have passed it along. I fully agree that this situation is ridiculous.

Comment: @TomWarner you miss the point. The point is that **your code** shouldn't create and copy new `byte[]` buffers around. It's *your* code that should reuse buffers. Does that API have  a method that accepts a `PipeReader` instead of a `ReadOnlyMemory<>` though? That would be even more efficient.

Comment: So the appeal of your answer is that it doesn't use extra buffers to copy the data around? And the API does not accept a PipeReader. It really makes no sense to me why it requires a ReadOnlyMemory<byte> because as far as I can tell it should just accept a string instead, but here we are.

Comment: That's the whole point of using Memory and Span. Search SO for `OutOfMemoryException`. In almost *no* case was RAM exhausted. In almost all cases, there were so many garbage objects that no new objects could be allocated. Naively reading a large CSV by splitting along lines and commas can cause 10x worse performance for just this reason. And throw OOM exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way I found is by converting the string to a byte[] and returning that as ReadOnlyMemory, like so:

```
var memory = new ReadOnlyMemory<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str));
```

Comment: Not really. For starters, .NET strings are UTF16. No information will be lost, but that's still a conversion. More importantly, `Encoding.GetBytes()` creates a new buffer, so what's the point of using `ReadOnlyMemory` ?

Comment: It would be better to use one of the [GetBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodingextensions.getbytes?view=net-5.0) extension methods that write to an `IBufferWriter`, eg an [ArrayBufferWritter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraybufferwriter-1?view=net-5.0) or a PipelineWriter. This way you can reuse buffers between calls. You can use [WrittenMemorry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraybufferwriter-1.writtenmemory?view=net-5.0#system-buffers-arraybufferwriter-1-writtenmemory) to get the bytes

Answer (score 4):

Thee *is* a way. The [EncodingExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodingextensions?view=net-5.0) class contains [GetBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodingextensions.getbytes?view=net-5.0) extension methods that can write to an [IBuffeWriter< T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.ibufferwriter-1?view=net-5.0). Two built-in classes implement this interface, [ArrayBufferWriter<>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraybufferwriter-1?view=net-5.0) and [PipeWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipelines.pipewriter?view=net-5.0).

In APIs that use System.IO.Pipelines it's better to write to a PipeWriter directly rather than create an intermediate object. I'll use `ArrayBufferWriter` instead, because ... it's easier. It still allows memory to be reused instead of allocating new buffers:

```
var text=".....";
var writer=new ArrayBufferWrite(8192);

Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text,writer);

var memory=writer.WrittenMemory;
```

[WrittenMemoy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraybufferwriter-1.writtenmemory?view=net-5.0) returns a `ReadOnlyMemory<T>` object with the written data.

The buffer can be cleared with [Reset()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraybufferwriter-1.clear?view=net-5.0) and reused :

```
var writer=new ArrayBufferWrite(8192);
while(true)
{
    writer.Reset();
    var text=SomehowGetString();
    
    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text,writer);

    var memory=writer.WrittenMemory;
    ...
}
```